# How get `Class<Long>`?

Tags: kotlin

For reflection, I need a `Class<Long>` as argument to `getDeclaredMethod`:

```
it.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("myMethodName", Long.javaClass)
```

But in Kotlin, `Long.javaClass` gives a `Class<Long.companion>`. How do I get the correct type?

Comment: It seems that `123L.javaClass` gives `Class<Long>`, but it should not be necessary to instantiate a Long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Long::class` to get a [`KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html) representing `Long`, and then from there, the [`.java`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.html) extension property to get a Java `Class` instance. So altogether:

```
val longClass: Class<Long> = Long::class.java
```